# How to Dynamically Update Row Values in Pandas Dataframe Column?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, series

I have a csv file of fbi crime statistics. It is grouped by state, then city. The problem is that each state only has one row per grouping, so after the first state every subsequent value for that series is NaN until the next state.

My code so far is just me pulling in the csv with with pandas read_csv function, I truncated the last few rows because they're irrelevant.

```
crime = pd.read_csv('crime-stats-by-state-and-city-2010.csv', nrows=9310)
# df looks like:
            city       |   etc...
state
ALABAMA     Abbeville
NaN         Adamsville
NaN         Addison
...         ...
CALIFORNIA  Adelanto
NaN         Alameda
```

My question is how I could go through the state column and replace each NaN value with the correct state. I think what I want to do is iterate though each row and check if the current item is NaN or a state. If it's a state, then I want each subsequent NaN value to be the same value until I get to the next state, at which I will repeat the same process.

Would prefer tips/hints/explanations over just code, but beggars can't be choosers.

Comment: This is `ffill()`. But it looks like `state` might be your index.

Comment: Awesome! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Initially I though about using *reindex(method='ffill')*,
but it is applicable only in cases when the index is monotonically
increasing or decreasing.

Since we have no guarantee about the index order, we have to use
a 3-stage approach:

- reset the index (make *state* a regular column),
- call *ffill* on this column,
- set the index back to *state*.

The code to do it is:

```
df.reset_index(inplace=True)
df.state = df.state.ffill()
df.set_index('state', inplace=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like:

```
df.reset_index(inplace=True)
df['state'].fillna(method='ffill', inplace=True)
```